# replace values in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have an R data.frame object

```
long   <- c(100.25,100.75,100.75,100.75,100.75,100.75,101.25,99.25,99.25,100.25)
vars  <- c(1750.8, 1789.7, 1788.1, 1782.8, 1867.3, 1771.3, 1789.9, 1820.6, 1789.1, 1868.9)
varp  <- c(1470.714, 1279.862, 1306.740, 1190.296, 1762.874, 1464.975, 1619.855, 1744.476,
            1879.743, 2052.337)
df1 <- data.frame(varp,vars,long)
```

I would like to replace all values in **vars** by NA which satisfy folowing condition

```
(df$long <= 100.75 & df$long >= 100.25)
```

I have tried

```
ind<- which(df1$long <= 100.75 & df1$long >= 100.25)
```

i get

```
ind
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6 10 #
```

which are the TRUE values of above condition

and if I use

```
df1$vars[-ind]
[1] 1789.9 1820.6 1789.1 #
```

I get FLASE value of above condition

could somebody please tell me how I can  replace these FALSE Index in **vars** by NA in data.frame?

Answer (score 0):

I just used `df1$vars[-ind]=NA` and it works fine.

Thank you